# YAAS Cloud Foundry - What domain does the builder module config expect

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am following the Yaas tutorial on how to create a builder module. [(link to tutorial)](https://devportal.yaas.io/gettingstarted/createabuildermodule/index.html#2)  In this section of the tutorial they discuss a manifest.yml file that describes the configuration for a builder module.

```
---
applications:
- name: ######
  host: ######
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git
  instances: 1
  memory: 256M
  domain: ######
```

It is not clear what the domain attribute refers to, what should the domain attribute point to?

Answer (score 0):

The domain instructs `cf`, the command line client for Cloud Foundry, which domain you'd like it to use.

On your Cloud Foundry platform, there can be multiple domains registered.  There will be at least one registered as the default and zero or more other domains registered.  You can omit the `domain` attribute in your `manifest.yml` file and CF will use the default domain.  If you'd like to use a specific, non-default domain then you can include it in the `manifest.yml` file.

Ex:

```
---
applications:
- name: ######
  host: ######
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git
  instances: 1
  memory: 256M
  domain: example.com
```

Where `example.com` is available in the output from `cf domains`.

```
$ cf domains
Getting domains in org example as user@example.com...
name                 status   type
cfapps.io            shared
cf-tcpapps.io        shared   tcp
example.com          owned
```

More details in the docs here.

http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#domain